# `fetchQuery.toPromise()` in relay 11: What is 3D data?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay

In relay 11, `fetchQuery` has been overhauled to return an `Observable` object.

To get the old behavior from prior relay versions, you can use `fetchQuery_deprecated`, or `.toPromise()` on the observable itself. But there's a warning:

> **Behavior with `.toPromise`**
>
> If desired, you can convert the request into a Promise using **`.toPromise()`**. Note that toPromise will start the query and return a Promise that will resolve when the first piece of data returns from the server and cancel *further processing*. That means any deferred or 3D data in the query may not be processed. **We generally recommend against using toPromise() for this reason**.

Emphasis theirs.  https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/fetch-query/#behavior-with-topromise

What is 3D and deferred data?  Are there any concrete examples of what is being talked about here?

Comment: https://relay.dev/docs/glossary/#3d?